# How to change width of popup for different child classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

```
    <span class="grandparent">
        <span class='parent'>
            <span id="popUP" class="child1">
                Some content for popUP
             </span> <!-- 1st child has width of 390px-->
        </span>    
    </span>
```

Now for different options, say the child span tag is replaced by new tag as mentioned below.

```
     option A) <span id="popUP" class="child2"></span> 
             <!-- 2nd child has popUP width of 550px--> 
     option B) <span id="popUP" class="child3"></span>
             <!-- 3rd child has popUP width of 450px-->
     option C) <span id="popUP" class="child4"></span> 
              <!-- 4th child has popUP width of 350px-->
```

How to change the width of the popup dynamically using JavaScript or jQuery?? I tried using `.find()` method but it no luck

Comment: Which plugin you used so far for your popup ?

Comment: Care for IDs they should be unique for each element.

Comment: @Jai.... can i make use of classes which are unique for each element

Comment: How does the pop up look actually? Can you add your CSS as well?

Comment: @ insertusernamehere - i dont have them right now... it a regular popup with some content inside it

Comment: @ Divyesh Patoriya - there is no specified plugin

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you do something like this instead? Your id and class are vice versa.

```
option A) <span class="popUP" id="child2"></span> 
            <!-- 2nd child has popUP width of 550px--> 
option B) <span class="popUP" id="child3"></span>
             <!-- 3rd child has popUP width of 450px-->
option C) <span class="popUP" id="child4"></span> 
              <!-- 4th child has popUP width of 350px-->
```

then do something like this?

```
$("#child2").addClass("width2");
```

then the css

```
.width2
{
width:550px;
}
```

consider using div. I've read somewhere span ignore tags. and posting the whole code might help.

Comment: @Arthy : it worked Thanks .. is there any other way to do that?

Comment: @mvemula 1. if it worked, why do you want any other way? Does it interrupt your other codes? 2. Posting the whole code makes it much easier to see actually you want to achieve, and we can discuss more. 3. Please accept my answer if it worked. :-)
P/S: please consider looking into jquery UI dialog/bootstrap modal. Makes your whole life a lot easier.